# Change default values for certain attributes for future NSManagedObject insertions?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

How could I go about doing this programmatically? Subclass NSManagedObject and override `-(void)awakeFromInsert;`? Then I suppose set the attribute values in the methods implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The way to get Core Data to do this, and IMO the right way to handle the situation, is to add another version of the model with the default values set on those properties, and configure automatic model migration.

I don't know whether migration will apply the new defaults to existing entities with nil values. (My guess would be not. Testing would bear the answer.)

Is there some reason you need to leave alone existing entities with nil values?

`-awakeFromInsert` would indeed be the right place to do this kind of thing in code.

Comment: Oh, come to think of it, you are correct, I would need to update the default values of existing entities as well.

Comment: I do know that if you set the properties as required, that migration will apply them to existing elements with nil values.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please click the check mark next to the answer to mark it accepted.